# node-sass watch changes in @imports

Tags: css, sass, watch, node-sass

I am running following command. When I change something in imported file './style/custom' the sass is not automatically recompiled as expected.

What is a correct command for node-sass to follow @imports and watch them?

```
node-sass --watch --recursive local.sass --follow --indented-syntax 
--output-style nested --source-map true local.css
```

local.sass - looks as following

```
/*
 ***************************
 file: ./style/bootstrap/bootstrap-sass
 ***************************
 */

@import ./style/bootstrap/bootstrap-sass


/*
 ***************************
 file: ./style/bower_components
 ***************************
 */
@import ./style/bower_components


/*
 ***************************
 file: ./style/asset_css
 ***************************
 */
@import ./style/asset_css


/*
 ***************************
 file: ./style/custom.sass
 ***************************
 */
@import ./style/custom
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

node-sass --watch works if you put imports in quotation marks. Issue is in sass-graph witch does not work with indented sass syntax.

Link to git issue:
https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/1179

```
/*
 * **************************
 * file: ./style/bootstrap/bootstrap-sass
 * **************************
 */

@import './style/bootstrap/bootstrap-sass'


/*
 * **************************
 * file: ./style/bower_components
 * **************************
 */
@import './style/bower_components'


/*
 * **************************
 * file: ./style/custom.sass
 * **************************
 */
@import './style/custom'
```